# How to compute the error threshold for the $9$-qubit Shor code?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, error-correction

I was trying to calculate the threshold of $9$-qubit Shor's code. The error channel is

$$E=(1-p)I+p/3X+p/3Y+p/3Z.$$

But I got the threshold is equal to 1. How can I get the right threshold (I believe it will be smaller than 0.5)? I tried to code by Qiskit but still wrong...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compute a threshold, you need to figure out the probability of an error occurring despite the error-correction ($\bar{p}$), and then compare it to the chance without error-correction ($p$).  The threshold is given by $\bar{p}<p$.  For the Shor code, we know that it can correct an arbitrary single-qubit error on any one of the 9 qubits, so the chance that the code *correctly* functions is
\begin{align}
(1-p)^9 \quad[\text{no error}] + 9p(1-p)^8 \quad[\text{9 ways of having 1 error}]
\end{align}
The chance that the code fails is the complement of this probability, i.e. when two or more errors occur
\begin{align}
\bar{p} &= 1 - ((1-p)^9 + 9p(1-p)^8)\\
&= 1 -((1-p)^8 - p(1-p)^8 + 9p(1-p)^8)\\
&= 1 - (1+8p)(1-p)^8
\end{align}
which is the bound that Shor computes in his original [paper](https://www.cs.miami.edu/home/burt/learning/Csc670.052/pR2493_1.pdf).  The threshold is when the logical error rate just beats out the physical error rate, which comes out to around 3.23%.

Comment: Hi, what if we have different probabilities? I.e. if the channel is $(1-p)I+p_xX\rho X^{\dagger}+p_yY\rho Y^{\dagger}+p_zZ\rho Z^{\dagger}$, with $p=p_x+p_y+p_z$.