# How to calculate pseudo-threshold of the [[5,1,3]] code analytically to match simulation?

Tags: error-correction, measurement, simulation, stabilizer-code

In [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15785/19679) there is a simple method given to compute the "worst case pseudo-threshold" of the Shor code. I want to apply this to the $[[5,1,3]]$ perfect code. Namely, given a depolarizing channel (where the probability that $X$, $Y$ ,or $Z$ happens is $p/3$ and the probability that $I$ happens is $1-p$) we can compute the probability of a logical error as
$$
p_L^\text{worst-case} = 1-( (1-p)^5 + 5 p (1-p)^4).
$$
Basically the reasoning is that because the code has distance $d=3$ we can correct weight-0 errors (which happen with probability $(1-p)^5$) and we can correct weight-1 errors (which happen with probability $p(1-p)^4$ and there are 5 of them). Then we take the complement to find the probability of a logical error.

However, this is a "worst-case" calculation because it assumes anytime we get an error above weight-1 the code fails, which isn't necessarily true (as mentioned in [this answer to my previous question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/35848/19679)).

On the other hand (and mentioned in the previous question) we can try to find $p_L$ by simulating the decoding of the $[[5,1,3]]$ code in Mathematica (I used 30000 trials because it seemed smooth enough). I have plotted the probability of a logical error (y-axis) vs probability of a physical error $p$ (x-axis) for both $p_L^\text{worst-case}$ (red) and $p_L^\text{simulation}$ (blue) below. We clearly see that $p_L^\text{worst-case}$ approximates $p_L^\text{simulation}$ pretty well for small values of $p$ but deviates significantly for higher values of $p$.
[image]

I am interested in analytically deriving $p_L$ (the blue line) from first principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find an exact expression for the blue line you could one by one check for each physical error if it leads to a logical error. For a five qubit code with a code capacity noise model this is doable as there are $4^5 = 1024$ different errors (smaller than your number of trials).

For analytically calculating the pseudo-threshold I expect you can get close by checking up to weight 2 errors.

---

Examples of some high weight errors that are correctable:

- Errors that are a stabilizer and act as the identity.
- Weight 3 errors that are stabilizer equivalent to weight one errors.

Answer (score 2):

In accordance with what @Peter-Jan said, what I was failing to understand is that if an error is "within weight-1" of a stabilizer element then it is correctable. For example suppose the weight-5 error $E = XZZXY$ occurs. We can decompose this error as
$$
XZZXY = IIIIY \cdot XZZXI.
$$
The element $XZZXI$ is in the stabilizer and so it won't affect the codewords and so this error is equivalent to the weight-1 error $IIIIY$, which we can correct because the code has distance $3$.

As suggested, I went into Mathematica and figured out which errors were correctable (those that are within a weight-1 error of a stabilizer element). We get the following table.

\begin{array} {|c|c|}\hline \text{Weight} & \text{Num Correctable Errors} & \text{Num Total Errors} \\ \hline 0 & 1 &1 \\ \hline 1 & 15 &15 \\ \hline 2 & 0 & 90\\ \hline 3 & 60 & 270 \\ \hline 4 & 135 & 405 \\ \hline 5 & 45 & 243\\ \hline  \end{array}

Then the probability of logical error is
$$
p_L = 1 -( (1-p)^5 + 15 (p/3)(1-p)^4 + 60 (p/3)^3 (1-p)^2 + 135 (p/3)^4(1-p) + 45 (p/3)^5 ).
$$

If we plot this on top of the simulated data points we get the following figure (where the purple line is $p_L$).
[image]
So we see that this is the correct probability of logical error.

We can also compute the pseudo-threshold (or breakeven point) by setting $p_L = p$. We find that $p_{th} = \frac{3-\sqrt{6}}{4} \approx 0.137628$ which is an improvement over the "worst-case" pseudo-threshold of $0.131123$.